# Find $f\in C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ such that the orbit map $[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto T(t)f\in C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Consider the map
$$T\colon[0,\infty)\to\operatorname{Lin}(C_{b}(\mathbb{R}),C_{b}(\mathbb{R})),\qquad (T(t)f)(x):=f(x+t),$$
where $C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of bounded continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, endowed with the supremum norm. I am looking for a function $f\in C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ such that the orbit map
$$O_{f}\colon[0,\infty)\to C_{b}(\mathbb{R}),\qquad O_{f}(t):=T(t)f$$
is not continuous.

To find such a function, I considered the sequence $t_{n}:=\tfrac{1}{n}$ in $[0,\infty)$ and tried to find $f\in C_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$\|O_{f}(0)-O_{f}(t_{n})\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-f(x+\tfrac{1}{n})|\not\to0\qquad\text{as}\qquad n\to\infty.$$

The trivial examples, such as constant functions obviously do not work. Then I consider (bounded continuous) functions that behave like $\sqrt[3]{x}$ around $x=0$, because its slope becomes infinitely large, but this also doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any function which is not uniformly continuous would do.  Observe that continuous functions on compact sets are always uniformly continuous, so playing around the origin will not help.  It is better to think of a highly oscillatory behavior out to infinity.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks. That makes sense indeed! However, I am still struggling with finding an explitit (elegant) example.

Comment: Try $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$.